# What does this enum mean (IDA Pro)?

Tags: ida

Trying to teach myself how to use IDA Pro, and I'm stuck trying to understand this enum:

```
enum Input::Action, copyof_42, bitfield
```

Local type 42 is defined as:

```
typedef ChunkStatus::Enum
```

who's enum is:

```
enum {Nothing = 0x0,
      CustomTiles = 0xA,
      BasicTiles = 0x14,
      CorrectedTiles = 0x1E,
      Tiles = 0x28,
      Entities = 0x32,}
```

I know the Input::Action enum has values at least from 0 to 90.

Here's my questions:

What do the commas in the first statement mean?
Can I put a limit on the range of values that Input::Action can take?
I've loaded the PDB file, and have gotten the name of enum members for some of the other enums. Can I get names for the members of this enum?